# Unit testing multiple asserts

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to unit test a method in C# using MSTest. I am testing that the password complexity is forced by the ChangePasswordAsync method. My problem is I want to test this method with a range of parameters. Currently i have a unit test with multiple asserts to test the different parameters, is this a reasonable solution?

I know when i have used other unit testing frameworks there have been ways to test a method with different parameters. Is there an attribute I can use upon the method to achieve this? My example unit test is below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures that a password must meet the password complexity of a digit and an alphanumeric, 8 digits long and one
    /// special character.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestPasswordComplexity()
    {
        var result = _UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(_TestUser.Id, "Password123!", "1!").Result; //Changes the password.

        Assert.IsFalse(result.Succeeded);

        result = _UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(_TestUser.Id, "Password123!", "123456789").Result; //Changes the password.

        Assert.IsFalse(result.Succeeded);

        result = _UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(_TestUser.Id, "Password123!", "123456789!").Result; //Changes the password.

        Assert.IsFalse(result.Succeeded);

        result = _UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(_TestUser.Id, "Password123!", "abcdefghijk").Result; //Changes the password.

        Assert.IsFalse(result.Succeeded);

        result = _UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(_TestUser.Id, "Password123!", "abcdefghijK1!").Result; //Changes the password.

        Assert.IsTrue(result.Succeeded);
    }
```

Or alternatively would you break each one into seperate unit tests?

Comment: Have one Assert per test. Split into different tests and name them accordingly

Comment: Even though there are multiple asserts this is logically a single test - you've named it well and it does what it says - it tests password complexity. Breaking this out into multiple test methods adds nothing except increases the number of tests which need to be executed.

Comment: @TomRedfern thats not true what you are saying. Breaking in seperate tests will result in better understanding and better maintainability if maybe the 3rd assert will fail. In the above scenario only the one test will fail, but if you have one assert per test, than the 4 other tests will still be valid. So you don't have to debug to find the line, which causes the test to fail.

Comment: @Dom84 I conceed your point about test failure resolution granularity- yes you may save yourself 10 seconds not having to debug into the test. However, what would you call the test method which should return fail with the input "123456789!"? public void ShouldNotSetPasswordValue123456789!()? To me, a failure in the current test method means I have broken the password complexity detection algorithm in some way. And that's all I need to know in order to fix the problem.

Comment: slight aside, but I would look at using specflow in in particular [Scenario Outlines](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Using-Gherkin-Language-in-SpecFlow#scenario-outlines) for this as it makes adding new cases extremely simple

Comment: well, why not naming the method ShouldNotSetPasswordValue123456789()? What would be the problem? But thats more a discussion about preferences in naming conventions and at least also of your own preferences in look and feel of your code i think.

Answer (score 3):

You can add data row annotations.

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow ("1!")
[DataRow ("123456789")
[DataRow ("123456789!")
...
public void TestPasswordComplexity(string pass)
{
    var result = _UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(_TestUser.Id, "Password123!", pass).Result; //Changes the password.

    Assert.IsFalse(result.Succeeded);
}
```

It will run the test method with each data row passed with the `pass` parameter.

Create a separate method for the fifth `Assert.IsTrue(result.Succeeded)` case

Answer (score 1):

Write for every test a separate unit test method with a meaning full name.
So when later on the test fails you find out easily what's the problem.

You have to distinguish between different tests and different test parameters.
Some of your asserts will fail because the password is for some reason to weak, some
should pass.

For the case where you really need different parameters, there is the possibility to use `DataSource` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx) where you can add an external source as excel file for input.

E.g you could test passing passwords with the excel source.